# How do I consume an API using ASP.net Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

Sample Json:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "ProfileID": "1001",
      "Name": "Jane Doe",
      "HomePhone": "555-1212",
      "Address1": "123 Elm St"
    },
    {
      "ProfileID": "1002",
      "Name": "Rick Fox",
      "HomePhone": "555-1213",
      "Address1": "123 Ok St"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code so far:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private void popGrid()
{
   var client = new HttpClient();
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://the-api/");
   var responseTask = client.GetAsync("member-list");
   responseTask.Wait();
   var result = responseTask.Result;
   if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      var read_response = responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      read_response.Wait();
      var read_result = read_response.Result;

      dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(read_result);
      var success = response.success;
      var status = response.status;
      var data = response.data;

      // List<Root> myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(data);

      if ((bool)success)
      {
         GridView1.DataSource = data;
         GridView1.DataBind();
      }
   }

}

public class Root
{
   public string ProfileID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string HomePhone { get; set; }
   public string Address1 { get; set; }
}
```

The Errors:
If I run the code as written, it runs through all the way without issue. However when the page renders I get an ugly error:

```
    Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' in Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' is not marked as serializable.
```

Buried in the Stack Trace is one line that gives a clue(to me):

```
    [ArgumentException: Error serializing value '1001' of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.']
```

**So then I the added the (commented) line that uses the Root class**.
However, if I un-comment that line and run the code, I get the following error:

```
    Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.List<Root>>(string)' has some invalid arguments'
```

The above error seems to indicate that JsonConvert.DeserializeObject won't accept the var 'data' as an input. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

**Based on the accepted answer this is my final working solution:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

const string theAPI = "http://the-api/";
const string otherAPI = "http://other-api/";

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromAPI(theAPI, "member-list");
   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      GridView1.DataSource = dt;
      GridView1.DataBind();
      GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
   }
   else
   {
      // nothing found
   }
}

public DataTable GetDataTableFromAPI(string api, string endPoint) 
{
   var client = new HttpClient();
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(api);
   var response = client.GetAsync(endPoint).Result;
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);
      var success = jsonParsed["success"];
      var status = jsonParsed["status"];
      if ((bool)success)
      {
         DataTable dt = jsonParsed["data"].ToObject<DataTable>();
         return dt;
      }
   }
   return new DataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is better to create async method , but if you can not , you have to fix your code

```
    var response = client.GetAsync(api).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
     var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     var jsonParsed=JObject.Parse(json);
     var success = jsonParsed["success"];
      var status = jsonParsed["status"];
      List<Root> data = jsonParsed["data"].ToObject<List<Root>>();
    
      //or in this case you don't need any custom classes at all

       DataTable data = jsonParsed["data"].ToObject<DataTable>();
      
    
      if ((bool)success)
      {
         GridView1.DataSource = data;
         GridView1.DataBind();
      }

     }
```

Comment: On the 3rd line of code (var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;), the keyword 'Content' is causing the error: HttpResponseMessage does not contain a definition for 'Content'.

Comment: @JonV  All the code I  post including this one has been tested.

Comment: Yes, I updated my above post to include my working solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the approach.  Instead of trying to deserialize only *part* of the JSON, deserialize the whole thing into an object.  Define an object structure which matches it:

```
public class Root
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Profile> data { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public string ProfileID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the response into that:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(read_result);
```

Then you can access the collection in that object:

```
GridView1.DataSource = result.data;
```

Comment: If you are planning to process multiple api's, you may need to define `Root<T> { T data ...}` so that the caller can define what data you expect.

Comment: Though this solution works fine, I ended up using Serge's solution as it removes the requirement to use a model/class.